# split array values into string value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am getting an array of shapes as follow..
my code is...

```
responseElement = [[bodyElement childrenNamed:@"GET_AllProductFrameShapeResponse"] objectAtIndex:0];
    resultElement = [[responseElement childrenNamed:@"GET_AllProductFrameShapeResult"] objectAtIndex:0];

    for (SMXMLElement *eventElements in [resultElement childrenNamed:@"Get_FrameShape"])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dicEventsData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [dicEventsData setValue:[eventElements valueWithPath:@"FrameShape"] forKey:@"FrameShape "];

        [frameShapeResult addObject:dicEventsData];
    }
    NSLog(@"frameShape result %@", frameShapeResult);
```

so get following array having directory of shapes

```
frameShape result (
        {
        "FrameShape " = OVEL;
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = Wayfarer;
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = "Club Master";
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = Aviator;
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = Wayferer;
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = Rectangle;
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = Round;
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = Oval;
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = "Cat-Eye";
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = "Cat Eye";
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = ClubRound;
    },
        {
        "FrameShape " = Square;
    }
)
```

i want following into One array from given array.. Dont know How to do that..

OVEL

Wayfarer

Club Master"

Aviator

Wayferer

Rectangle

Round

Oval

Cat-Eye

Cat Eye

ClubRound

Square

Thanks for Any help in advance..

Comment: you want all values in one string ?

Comment: Let we know What you want exactly... ?

Comment: Show some Code what have you done ? & where you are upto?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

**Space added in key**

```
NSArray * FrameShape = frameShaperesult; // array of you result which contains dictionary objects. 
FrameShape = [FrameShape valueForKey:@"FrameShape "]; // array that contains string objects which you mentioned in question
```

This final FrameShape array will contains only string as object and you can access each by for loop.

If you want all objects in one string try this:

```
NSString *str = [FrameShape componentsJoinedByString:@","]; // all object will join by ,(comma) you can change it as per your need.
```

Comment: str : <null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>

Comment: im getting blank string

Comment: @NilamGoswami This answer is correct, however your keys are `@"FrameShape "` and not `@"FrameShape"`.

Comment: Yes, There is a space after FrameShape. thanks @Droppy for correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follow to get only Array of shapes..

```
responseElement = [[bodyElement childrenNamed:@"GET_AllProductFrameShapeResponse"] objectAtIndex:0];
resultElement = [[responseElement childrenNamed:@"GET_AllProductFrameShapeResult"] objectAtIndex:0];

for (SMXMLElement *eventElements in [resultElement childrenNamed:@"Get_FrameShape"])
{
    [frameShapeResult addObject:[eventElements valueWithPath:@"FrameShape"]];
}
NSLog(@"frameShape result %@", frameShapeResult);
```

This will give you the exact result you want ..

Hope this help :)